# How can I ignore a field validation in flask-wtf?

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form to add an item to my database, which includes two buttons: `Cancel` and `Submit`. The problem I have is that when I press the `Cancel` button with an empty form, I get a `Please fill out this field.`  error instead of returning to my home page (see `views.py` for logic). So how can I get my app to ignore the `DataRequired` validators when I press the `Cancel` button?

`forms.py`:

```
class ItemForm(FlaskForm):
  id = StringField('id', validators=[DataRequired()]
  name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()]
  cancel = SubmitField('Cancel')
  submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

`views.py`:

```
def add_item()
  form = ItemForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    if form.submit.data:
      # Code to add item to db, removed for brevity.
    elif form.cancel.data:
      flash('Add operation cancelled')
      return redirect(url_for('home.homepage'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cancel button doesn't really need to be a submit button. You can simply have a normal button which takes the user back to the home page (using a `href` or capturing the `onclick` event).

If you still want the `cancel` button to be a WTForms field, one option would be to override the `validate` method in the form and remove the `DataRequired` validators on `id` and `name`. The below is untested but may give you a starting point to work from.

```
class ItemForm(FlaskForm):
  id = StringField('id')
  name = StringField('Name')
  cancel = SubmitField('Cancel')
  submit = SubmitField('Submit')

def validate(self):                                                         

    rv = Form.validate(self)                                                

    if not rv:                                                              
        return False                                                        

    if self.cancel.data
        return True

    if self.id.data is None or self.name.data is None:   
        return False                                                   

    return True
```

Comment: An even easier and, I think more correct, way of doing this is by adding `formnovalidate=True` in the template. For example `{{ form.delete_button(class_="...", formnovalidate=True) }}`.